# Is it possible to do animation with drawables?

Tags: android, drawable

I have been working on adding animation to the card game I have been programming lately, and recently added in these xml files:

slide_up_left.xml

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator" >

    <translate
        android:duration="@integer/config_slide_time"
        android:fromYDelta="100%p"
        android:toYDelta="0" />

    <alpha
        android:duration="@integer/config_slide_time"
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0" />

    <rotate
        android:duration="@integer/config_slide_time"
        android:fromDegrees="25"
        android:pivotX="0"
        android:pivotY="0"
        android:toDegrees="0" />

 </set>
```

slide_up_right.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator" >

    <translate
        android:duration="@integer/config_slide_time"
        android:fromYDelta="100%p"
        android:toYDelta="0" />

    <alpha
        android:duration="@integer/config_slide_time"
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0" />

    <rotate
        android:duration="@integer/config_slide_time"
        android:fromDegrees="-25"
        android:pivotX="100%"
        android:pivotY="0"
        android:toDegrees="0" />

</set>
```

integers.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
     <integer name="config_slide_time">800</integer>
</resources>
```

Shortly after, I came to the realize that my cards are drawables, so the only way I can get motion is by moving the entire canvas, and that's going to create too many problems. Is there any way I can move the cards individually without the canvas, or am I going to have to reset all the cards as images instead of drawables?

Comment: how are you using those cards `drawable`s? Are you drawing them yourself in `onDraw` of a `View`?

Comment: Yes, I am using them in onDraw

Comment: I think in this way, if you have your own view, you need to write your own animation behavior inside onDraw method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the android.view.animation package is meant for animating Views, you will have to manage the animations yourself, although you can still use your animations that you have defined in XML.

I'm assuming you are doing the drawing in some custom View.

First, define a Transformation variable and an Animation variable in your View class:

```
private Animation mAnimation;
private Transformation mTransformation = new Transformation();
```

When you want to start the Animation, inflate one:

```
mAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.slide_up_left);
```

Then, set the start time and initialize the size:

```
mAnimation.setStartTime(getDrawingTime());
Rect drawableBounds = mDrawable.getBounds();
mAnimation.initialize(drawableBounds.width(), drawableBounds.height(), getWidth(), getHeight());
```

Now, in `onDraw()`, pass in the current time and the transformation to update the transformation, and then apply it to the canvas before drawing:

```
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    mAnimation.getTransformation(getDrawingTime(), mTransformation);
    s.save();
    s.concat(mTransformation.getMatrix());
    mDrawable.setAlpha((int) (mTransformation.getAlpha() * 0xFF));
    mDrawable.draw(canvas);
    s.restore();
}
```

That's a basic approach to doing it yourself. You'll have to manage the state of the animation, clean it up when the animation is over, create and position the Drawable(s), and handle nulls and other View state, but this should give you a starting point.

I would also highly recommend looking into ObjectAnimator, which is the new and better way to do animations.